# Predict probability of y=1 for x step ahead with probit model

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, data-science, statsmodels

I'm working on reproducing a probit model with python statsmodel. The data is a time series data and the formula for the probit model is defined as Pr(Yt+H=1|Xt)=Φ(β0+β1Xt).

Yt is a binary variable defined by the probit model. The objective of the probit model is to predict the probability that Yt = 1 at t+H, given a set of predictors Xt. The H-step ahead means the date forecasted for the time series is H-days ahead. So instead of predicting Pr(Yt=1) at Xt, I want to find Pr(Yt+H=1) at Xt.

Can the model be implemented with python statsmodel  `statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Probit`? I think the probit model implements the formula Pr(Yt=1)=Φ(β0+β1Xt) by default. But I am not sure how or if it is possible to specify the conditional probability and how to define the "H-step ahead" with the options given by the model. I also found that `ConditionalLogit` statsmodel allows for defining the conditional, but I am not sure it is the right one to use here.

Comment: Suggest redirect to https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: If X are exogenous, then you can just use `Probit(y_t ~ x_{t-H})`, i.e. regress y on the lagged x.